# What is the difference between these 2 types of drivers?

Tags: led

I have a small doubt about LED Drivers. I have recently studied 2 posts related to LED Drivers - one is LED Driver Circuit and the Other one is Bipolar LED Driver Circuit. Those 2 posts links are also mentioning here for your reference:

1. [LED driver](http://www.electronicshub.org/230v-led-driver-circuit/)
2. [Bipolar LED driver](http://www.electronicshub.org/bipolar-led-driver-circuit/)

It is mentioned that the main advantages of these circuits are for indication purposes, home lighting and decoration purposes. But, is it not possible to use any one of the above circuits to handle all the cases? I mean, is it not possible to use the bipolar LED Driver circuit to operate both bipolar leds and also the normal LEDs by just making small changes in the values or connections?

Can anybody explain in detailed way about the main difference and working of both kinds of drivers?

Comment: Bipolar and bicolor LEDs are the same?

Comment: @nidhin: Bipolar LEDs only have 2 terminals.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration used to drive a bipolar LED is an [**H-bridge**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge), where the half-bridges are two push-pull outputs of one or more digital devices. While it is possible to drive a unipolar LED with an H-bridge, there is no benefit to having the voltage reversed on it and so one can save an output by tying the other end of the LED to either V<sub>CC</sub> or to ground, depending on which terminal is connected to the output.